# How to weight dictionary values via formula in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a formula from dictionary. This is my formula:

```
result = (1/1 * value1) + (1/2 * value2) + (1/3*value3) + ..N
```

This is my example dictionary:

```
StudentGrades = {0: [1, 2, 3, 4], 1: [5, 8, 10]} .
```

so it should return `{0: 4, 1: 12.33}`.

This is my code

```
avgDict = {}
x = 1
for k,v in StudentGrades.items():
    avgDict[k] = float(sum(1 / x * v))
    x += 1
```

my actual code returns `{0: 10.0, 1: 0.0}`.
So please can you solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` provides a solution for this:

```
import numpy as np

StudentGrades = {0: [1, 2, 3, 4], 1: [5, 8, 10]}

Result = {k: np.dot(v, [1/i for i in range(1, len(v)+1)])\
             for k, v in StudentGrades.items()}

# {0: 4.0, 1: 12.333333333333332}
```